# TableView SectionIndexTitles margin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

How to set SectionIndexTitles after cell and header. 
Like this UI.

[image]

It's currently looking like

[image]

I have tried to apply content Inset but when click on indextitle inset become 0 and left side also cut cell . How to resolve it ?

ContactsTableView.ContentInset = new UIEdgeInsets(0, -15, 0 , 0);

Comment: If you add index in sectionIndexTitlesForTableView and tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex override function, then it should come by default.

Comment: @Prasanth That's not concern. I have designed already. Just for spacing issue.

Comment: I test the sample [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/tables/populating-a-table-with-data#Adding_an_Index) and the default behavior of index is like what you want. Can you share some code to reproduce the problem? And how did you implement the index?

Comment: Same like in this example @JackHua-MSFT

Comment: I know you want the same of the example, did you follow the code in the example?